# $\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{1+X_1^2+...X_n^2}]=\sigma \sqrt n$

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

> Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be i.i.d with $\mathbb{E}[X_1]=0$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]=\sigma^2$.
> Prove $$\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{1+X_1^2+...X_n^2}]=\sigma \sqrt n$$

It might not be true but I feel like it is (or at least at the limit it is).

I needed to solve a problem and if I could show this I would finish, but realized I have no idea how to show it and I'm not even sure if its true.

The original problem is

> Prove $\frac{\sqrt{1+X_1^2+...X_n^2}}{\sqrt n}\overset{d}{\rightarrow}\sigma$ or $\frac{\sqrt{1+X_1^2+...X_n^2}}{\sqrt n}\overset{p}{\rightarrow}\sigma$

I'm taking a course in probability theory.

Thank you,

Comment: For fixed $n$ and $\sigma\to0$ the left-hand side converges to $1$ whereas the right-hand side vanishes, so it cannot be an equality.

Comment: The problem statement as written has to be incorrect, because if $X_1 = 2, -2$ with probability 1/2 each, we see that $E[X_1^2] = 4$, which would imply that $4 = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{1/n + 4}.$
Do you have access to the strong law of large numbers?

Comment: Yes thank you, I corrected the problem.
Also you are right, that for a finite sum it is not true, but what about the limit?

Comment: In the limit you can take $0= X_1=X_2= ...$. Then the equality you suggest says that $1=0$

Comment: If you take the square root out of the expectation, then you have that $\Bbb E[1+\sum X_i^2]=1+ n\sigma^2$, maybe you can start from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality you suggest may not be true for example if $X_i$ takes the values $-1$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$.

However, for your original problem, you can use the fact that if $(Y_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a sequence of non-negative random variables which converges in probability to some $y$, then $\left(\sqrt{Y_n}\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converges in probability to $\sqrt y$ (this is a special case of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4163769/continuous-functions-preserve-convergence-in-probability-proof-from-definition)). Use this with $Y_n=\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2\right)/n$ and a well-known theorem.

Comment: Hi, thank you, If you mean the CLT theorem I dont see how to use it, since  Im not dividing by $\sqrt(n)$. If I understand you correctly
$$ \frac{1+\sum X_i^2}{n}=\frac{1+\sum X_i^2-n\sigma +n\sigma}{n}\overset{d}{\rightarrow} 0+\sigma$$

I dont understand the reasoning for the last arrow.
I tried just now to prove it showing that the characteristics function converges but got 
$$ \phi_{Z_n}\rightarrow \phi_Z,\ \  \phi_{Z_n/\sqrt(n)}(t)=\phi_{Z_n}(t/\sqrt(n))\rightarrow \phi_Z(0)=1$$

Comment: I meant the weak law of large numbers.

Comment: Ah, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The Markov inequality might be used in conjunction. Let's write
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(\left|\sqrt{\frac{1+x_{1}^{2}+\dots x_{n}^{2}}{n}}-\sigma\right|\geq\epsilon)\leq\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\mathbb{E}\left(\left|\sqrt{\frac{1+x_{1}^{2}+\dots x_{n}^{2}}{n}}-\sigma\right|\right)}{\epsilon}$ then iff $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}\left(\left|\sqrt{\frac{1+x_{1}^{2}+\dots x_{n}^{2}}{n}}-\sigma\right|\right)=0$ we will have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\sqrt{\frac{1+x_{1}^{2}+\dots x_{n}^{2}}{n}}-\sigma\right|\geq\epsilon\right)=0$ which is convergence in probability. Therefore, the stronger condition $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}\left(\left|\sqrt{\frac{1+x_{1}^{2}+\dots x_{n}^{2}}{n}}-\sigma\right|\right)=0$ implies $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+x_{1}^{2}+\dots x_{n}^{2}}{n}}\right)=\sigma$ using the fact that $\mathbb{E}\left(|X_{n}|\right)\geq \mathbb{E}\left(X_{n}\right).$